# Error in downloading and saving image using python

Tags: python

I written a code for downloading and saving images from a site .It worked nicely,but for some urls it is being showing an error.I have paste code below

```
import urllib2
import webbrowser

imageurl='http://www.example.com/'+image[s]
opener1 = urllib2.build_opener()
page1=opener1.open(imageurl)
my_picture=page1.read()
image1=image[s].replace("/","")
fout = open('images/tony/'+image1, "wb")
fout.write(my_picture)
fout.close()
```

Actually i get many values of image[s] and is working almost condition.But when the value of image[s]=images/PG013001 GROUP 2.jpg, the compiler gives an error

```
  File "leather.py", line 37, in get_leather
    page1=opener1.open(imageurl)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\urllib2.py", line 395, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\urllib2.py", line 508, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\urllib2.py", line 433, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\urllib2.py", line 367, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\urllib2.py", line 516, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I thought the corresponding imageurl ie 'http://www.example.com/images/PG013001 GROUP 2.jpg' doesn,t exist but when it is checked it exist.Please suggest a fix

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urls can't include spaces directly; it's simply not allowed.  What you want to do is to quote, or encode the spaces in the filename, so that the url becomes legal.  [Here's wikipedia on the matter.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

So, you want to quote the urls that you pass to urllib2.  In your code, you could do that by changing the one line to look like this:

```
page1=opener1.open(urllib2.quote(imageurl))
```

That oughta do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the link.  Try this:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote("images/PG013001 GROUP 2.jpg")
'images/PG013001%20GROUP%202.jpg'
```